# Vue convert string to dom (Nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to add dom in vue element, but it doesnt work.
here is my code,

```
<div v-bar="{preventParentScroll: true}">
  <div>
    <el-menu
      ref="menu"
      default-active=""
      class="lnbmenu"
      :unique-opened="true">
     **{{ this.menuList}}**
     </el-menu>
   </div>
```

and next, js code.

```
computed: {
  menuList(){ 
      ~~~ reducer ~~~ 
      return dom

      *//return 
       <el-submenu index="M0010">    
        <template slot='title'>     
         <span>menu1</span>    
        </template>
        <el-menu-item index="M0018">
         <nuxt-link to="tempMenu">  
          <span>menu2</span>
         </nuxt-link>
        </el-menu-item>
       </el-submenu>*
  }
}
```

I tried to use 'v-html' in el-menu tag, but still not work.
how can I add this thing?

Comment: What is the content of the list? Shouldn't you create a new element for each list item and insert them using a `v-for`?

Comment: Answer aside, there's no need for `this` in the template, you can just use the property/computed name `{{ menuList }}`.  In some cases, it won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you manipulate the DOM in Vue with the `$refs` keyword.

Have a look: https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/accessing-dom-refs